# Given a list of pairs, how to sort them by frequency of the second value?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a pair list such as `[(1, 1), (2, 5), (2, 1), (3, 3), (5, 3)]` by the frequency of the second term in each of the tuples. The resulting sorted list should be something like `[(3,3),(5,3),(1,1),(2,1),(2,5)]`. In this case, the frequency table would look like `1: 2, 3: 2, 5:1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [@John's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413629/given-a-list-of-pairs-how-to-sort-them-by-frequency-of-the-second-value/61413786#61413786) answer, we can build a frequency map using a [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then sort by the second value of each tuple using the frequencies from the dictionary, making sure we sort in reverse:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(1, 1), (2, 5), (2, 1), (3, 3), (5, 3)]

frequency_map = defaultdict(int)
for _, snd in lst:
    frequency_map[snd] += 1

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: frequency_map[x[1]], reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (5, 3), (2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Counter` to construct a `key` to pass to `sort` or `sorted` is a natural approach:

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = [(1, 1), (2, 5), (2, 1), (3, 3), (5, 3)]
counts = Counter(y for _,y in my_list)
sorted(my_list,key = lambda p:counts[p[1]],reverse = True)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (5, 3), (2, 5)]
```